# Rails - How to store time in rails, when difference between time is more than 18 hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I am using postgresql as my database.

Currently I have timing model, which contains `open_at` and `close_at` fields. Both fields' data type is time. When I select `open_at`, the time is 04:00, Rails default store it as `2000-01-01 04:00:00`

```
# schema.rb

create_table "timings", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string "day"
    t.time "open_at"
    t.time "close_at"
end
```

In my case store's open time is 08:00 and close time is 02:00, so when I store that time it stores it as:

```
=> #<Timing id: 3, day: "Tuesday", open_at: "2000-01-01 08:00:00", close_at: "2000-01-01 02:00:00", created_at: "2018-03-19 10:45:36", updated_at: "2018-03-20 06:34:16">
```

But when I want to get correct record it is not responding valid records.

The above timing record's opening time is 8am and closing time is 2am. If the current time is 6:46am, and I do the below query:

```
2.4.2 :079 > Timing.where("open_at < ? and close_at > ?", Time.current, Time.current)
  Timing Load (0.7ms)  SELECT  "timings".* FROM "timings" WHERE (open_at < '2018-03-20 06:48:09.004429' and close_at > '2018-03-20 06:48:09.004496') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

... it should come back with a result, but the result is empty. When I change the closing time to 11pm which means 23:00:00, and run below query:

```
Timing.where("open_at < ? and close_at > ?", Time.current, Time.current)
  Timing Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  "timings".* FROM "timings" WHERE (open_at < '2018-03-20 06:49:12.307156' and close_at > '2018-03-20 06:49:12.307205') LIMIT $1  [["LIMIT", 11]]
 => #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Timing id: 3, day: "Tuesday", open_at: "2000-01-01 04:00:00", close_at: "2000-01-01 23:59:00", created_at: "2018-03-19 10:45:36", updated_at: "2018-03-20 06:49:07">]>
```

...a result is retuerned.

Can anybody explain me how to store times for this situation? Or how can I resolve this timing issue? If the difference between open at and close at times is more than 18 hours? Or how should I query if I want to get the correct records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should store the opening and closing times as integers in seconds or minutes, because comparing an arbitrary current date with a stored timestamp is not what you're really after. Instead of saying "compare the time now with these two dates", you need to say "compare the opening and closing times of day with the current time of day.

Then you need to do two comparisons based on the values of the open and close times

```
# get your curent seconds after midnight
seconds = Time.current.to_i - Time.current.midnight.to_i

# compare this to the open and close times
Timing.where("(open_at < close_at and open_at < :seconds and close_at > :seconds) or (open_at > close_at and (open_at < :seconds or close_at > :seconds))", {seconds: seconds})
```

**EDIT:** There was a tiny but fundamental error in my query above, fixed now. Always test your code kids!!

Comment: Thanks for the answer, as  per your answer suppose if admin select 02:00 than i need to store this `DateTime.parse("02:00").to_i` time. right ?

Comment: My opening time is ` Time.parse("08:00").to_i` , closing time is `Time.parse("01:00").to_i` and current time is `Mon, 26 Mar 2018 06:28:26 UTC +00:00`, since when i query above it is giving me result, result should not come because opening time is 8 AM, and current time is 06:28 AM

Comment: You don't need to do any DateTime parsing for the opening and closing times, just store them as straight integers. For example, 2am = 7200.

Comment: @Vishal - Sorry I made a big blunder in the code earlier, try with the new edit I just made

Comment: Actually your answer is working, i do it in this way `open_at = Time.parse("08:00").seconds_since_midnight.to_i` `close_at=Time.parse("16:10").seconds_since_midnight.to_i` and `seconds = Time.now.to_i - Time.now.midnight.to_i
` surprisingly it is working fine, may be it is same as your above comment. right ?

Comment: Yep, I think we're actually doing the same thing

Comment: Thank you so much for answer, worked for me :) , accepted your answer

Comment: There is little mistake in query, Can you please update your answer ?

Answer (score -1):

When parsing time information it’s important to never do it without specifying the time zone. The best way to do this is to use Time.zone.parse (which will use the time zone specified in config.time_zone) instead of just Time.parse (which will use the computer’s time zone).

Have you tried working with UTC? - Check out this [link](https://www.varvet.com/blog/working-with-time-zones-in-ruby-on-rails/)

Comment: its not issue, whenever i query , i always take Time.zone.now, so its working fine.

Comment: check the Dos and Donts section of the article I shared with you above.

Comment: Do it related to my question  ?

Comment: so why would I share it if it doesn't relate to your question?

Comment: I dont have issue of Parsing the time, or i also dont have issue of time zone, its working fine if close time is less than or equal to 23:59 PM

Comment: This question is not an issue of parsing time or timezones